# Match HTML tag's content with a Javascript RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, tags

I have the following HTML as a string in my JavaScript function:

```
<p>one</p> <p align='center'>two</p>
```

I want to extract this string:

`"onetwo"` (without quotes obviously)

Can you please suggest some pure JavaScript code (jQuery is also OK...) to get tags' content?

Comment: Don't use regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: +1 nice comment..he will repent now..:D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jQuery you don't need a complex regex, you can easily parse the HTML and use the DOM:

```
var s = "<p>one</p> <p align='center'>two</p>";
var wrapper = $('<div />').html(s);
var text = wrapper.text();
```

In this case `$(s).text()` would have also worked, but it will fail if you have free text on the first level (e.g. `<p>1</p>2`), so I usually avoid it.

Note that the result here is `"one two"` (not `"onetwo"`), because you have a space between the `<p>` tags.
If that's a problem, you can use `wrapper.children().text()` or `wrapper.find('p').text()`, for example, according to your exact needs.

Working example: http://jsbin.com/osidi3

Comment: NOT using RegEx is definitly the key to doing this :P

Answer (score 1):

I made the following Regex to grab content from XML tags. 
This will only work with a tag that has content and is followed by a closing tag. Will not get contents of tags that contain other tags.
The tag name is in capture group 1 and the tag content is in capture group 2. This will work to get all content including <, >, ", ' and & inside of tag content.

```
<([^\s>]+)\s?[^>]*>(.*)(?:<\/\1)>
```